# How to control segway motor with arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I salvaged segway motor with 8 wires. I did completed basic connection of 5 hall sensors and power from 36V lipo battery in the image  below. When I connect self-learning wires then motor starts rotating so connecting must be right. So now how do I control the motor with arduino?

Controller is kkmoon motor regulator 350W - [link](https://www.amazon.ae/KKmoon-Regulator-Controller-Electric-Brushless/dp/B07VTQC1QV/ref=asc_df_B07VTQC1QV/?tag=googleshopp09-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=379724527416&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5866853317310978478&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1000013&hvtargid=pla-868311548127&psc=1)

didn't find datasheet about motor but here are some Information:-
Type: BLDC Motor
Voltage: 36V
no of wires:- 8 (3 wires  for 3 phase, 5 for hall sensor)
Power:- 300W

[image: connections]

[image: motor controller information]

Comment: please provide a link to the motor datasheet

Comment: didn't find datasheet but posted some basic information above.